# "Datasets" or "data sets"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is correct, “dataset” or “data set”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/which-is-correct-dataset-or-data-set)

When writing about sets of data produced and analysed for a scientific experiment,  which of the two forms is most adequate for a piece of international scientific writing? Is it "datasets" or "data sets"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia suggests that either "dataset" or "data set" is acceptable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_set

Answer (score 3):

Either is fine.  [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20data%20set,a%20dataset&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows a preference for **data set**:

[image]

[COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows 44 results for *a data set*, and 11 for *a dataset*, the earliest of which occurred in 2004.

The fact that *data set* is more common than *dataset* is due to the fact that *dataset* only recently became acceptable, as compared with the original and hence more longstanding *data set*.